# PySpark create new columns based on the rank

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to add few new columns in a DataFrame based on the rank column

So, I have this table

| Store | Car | Price | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe's | Corolla | 10000 | 1 |
| Joe's | HB20 | 5000 | 2 |
| Joe's | Beetle | 1500 | 3 |
| Carl's | Golf | 7500 | 1 |
| Carl's | HB20 | 5500 | 2 |
| Carl's | Opala | 4500 | 3 |
| Carl's | Monza | 2500 | 4 |

I'd like to groupBy store and create three new columns with the three most expensive cars, like that:

| Store | 1_most_exp_car | 2_most_exp_car | 3_most_exp_car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe's | Corolla | HB20 | Beetle |
| Carl's | Golf | HB20 | Opala |

I've tried to make a sort and make a collect list like that:

```
grouped_df.groupBy('Store').agg(F.collect_list("car")).show()
```

But it returned a non-ordered array

I'm new on PySpark and I don't know how can I handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a filter first to keep only the most expensive cars for each store, and then do `groupby.pivot`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

(df.filter(df.rank <= 3)
   .withColumn('col', f.expr('concat(rank, "_most_exp_car")'))
   .groupby('Store')
   .pivot('col')
   .agg(f.first(df.Car))
 ).show()

+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Store|1_most_exp_car|2_most_exp_car|3_most_exp_car|
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|Carl's|          Golf|          HB20|         Opala|
| Joe's|       Corolla|          HB20|        Beetle|
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```